# Swift open a new view controller programmatically on top of a map from a button insider a popover and a cell

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview, popover, presentviewcontroller

I have a bit of an odd problem. Note that everything is done programmatically, so please no storyboard suggestions. Here's the setup:

I have a Master-Detail view layout, where the Detail view is a map. The Master-view's table is filled with cells that represent annotation points on the map. When you tap on a cell, it focuses on that annotation on the map and opens a custom annotation view using a popover. Likewise, when you tap the annotation itself, the same popover opens. So far, so good.

Now, inside the popover *and* inside each cell there is an a button which, when pressed, should open a new view **that fills the whole screen.** The view would have information specific to its corresponding annotation.

Here is how I am trying to do it:

**Class that has the map (MyDetailViewController)**

```
public func openNewViewController(){
    self.presentViewController(NewViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Function call for cell button and popover button**

```
func btnPressed(sender: AnyObject){
    var dvc = MyDetailViewController()
    dvc.openNewViewController()
}
```

When either button gets tapped, I get the same error:

Warning: Attempt to present `NewViewController` on `DetailViewController` whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

So, **what does it mean** that DetailViewController is not in the window hierarchy..? It must be since I see it, no?

Any idea **how to fix this issue**? Thanks in advance!

Comment: your function openNewViewController() is doing nothing!
just see the code ..... 
self.presentViewController(openNewViewController()) , animated : true , completion: nil) is pointing to  itself !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your function openNewViewController() is doing nothing!
See the code

```
self.presentViewController(openNewViewController()) , animated : true , completion: nil)
```

is pointing to  itself.

Instead try this :

```
public func openNewViewController(){
    var newController = UIViewController() // or any other view you wish to instantiate
    self.presentViewController(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Hi Sriram, thanks for the answer but that was a type-o. Good catch, but I intended to write `self.presentViewController(NewViewController()...)`. I edited my question

Comment: It's still the same error; the type-o was in the question, not in the actual code =)